# How to destroy jobs enqueued by resque workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scheduled-tasks, redis, resque

I'm using Resque on a rails-3 project to handle jobs that are scheduled to run every 5 minutes. I recently did something that snowballed the creation of these jobs and the stack has hit over 1000 jobs. I fixed the issue that caused that many jobs to be queued and now the problem I have is that the jobs created by the bug are still there and therefore It becomes difficult to test something since a job is added to a queue with 1000+ jobs.
I can't seem to stop these jobs. I have tried removing the queue from the redis-cli using the flushall command but it didn't work. Am I missing something? coz I can't seem to find a way of getting rid of these jobs.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you pop open a rails console, you can run this code to clear out your queue(s):

```
queue_name = "my_queue"
Resque.redis.del "queue:#{queue_name}"
```

Comment: As found in @denmarkin's answer below, use Resque.redis.del instead of Resque.redis.delete

Answer (score 71):

Playing off of the above answers, if you need to clear all of your queues, you could use the following:

```
Resque.queues.each{|q| Resque.redis.del "queue:#{q}" }
```

Answer (score 36):

Resque already has a method for doing this -  try `Resque.remove_queue(queue_name)` (see the documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/resque/Resque:remove_queue)). Internally it performs `Resque.redis.del()`, but it also does other cleanup, and by using an api method (rather than making assumptions about how resque works) you'll be more future-proof.

Comment: Using the Resque API is a better approach

Answer (score 14):

Updated rake task for clearing (according to latest redis commands changes): https://gist.github.com/1228863

Answer (score 14):

This is what works now:

```
Resque.remove_queue("...")
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the right way to do this: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/resque/1.27.4/Resque#remove_queue-instance_method

Answer (score 5):

It's safer and bulletproof to use the Resque API rather than deleting everything on the Resque's Redis. Resque does some cleaning in the inside.

If you want to remove **all** queues and associated enqueued jobs:

```
Resque.queues.each {|queue| Resque.remove_queue(queue)}
```

The queues will be re-created the next time a job is enqueued.

[Documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/resque/resque/Resque%3Aremove_queue)

Answer (score 4):

Enter redis console:

```
redis-cli
```

List databases:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
 1) "resque:schedules_changed"
 2) "resque:workers"
 3) "resque:queue:your_overloaded_queue"
```

`"resque:queue:your_overloaded_queue"` - db which you need.

Then run:

```
DEL resque:queue:your_overloaded_queue
```

Or if you want to delete specified jobs in queue then list few values from db with [`LRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> LRANGE resque:queue:your_overloaded_queue 0 2
1) "{\"class\":\"AppClass\",\"args\":[]}"
2) "{\"class\":\"AppClass\",\"args\":[]}"
3) "{\"class\":\"AppClass\",\"args\":[]}"
```

Then copy/paste one value to [`LREM`](http://redis.io/commands/lrem) command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> LREM resque:queue:your_overloaded_queue 5 "{\"class\":\"AppClass\",\"args\":[]}"
(integer) 5
```

Where 5 - number of elements to remove.

Comment: Redis recommends that you [not run `KEYS *` on a production database](https://redis.io/commands/keys) as it scans the entire set of keys and locks all records. This could adversely affect your background workers on a very busy system.